# NBA player to player match ups

Tags: basketball, statistics, nba

In the NBA, does the depth charts of one team match up with the depth charts in another team in terms of who will face who?

Let me explain:

Suppose the Celtics have Kemba Walker listed as a Starter for the Point Guard position and the 76ers have Ben Simmons listed as Starter for their Point Guard.

When the Celtics play the 76ers, is it safe to assume that Kemba Walker will face Ben Simmons on the court for most of the time that they are on the court on that game?

Whatever the answer is, will the same apply to Bench and Bench Warmers?

I hope I was clear thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter the order of when who plays who, my question is simply will Bench/Starter players from one team face the Bench/Starter on the other team consistently?

Comment: Different coaches have different substitution patterns, but for the most part, every team will start and end the game with their best 5 players on the court. So for at least that time of the game (barring foul trouble etc.), you can expect to see the starting point guards facing each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive rule or answer.  Defensive match ups are at the discretion of the coach or floor captain.

Players can have vastly different levels in skill in offense and defense. For example, take two opposing teams with skilled offensive point guards.  It is not uncommon to put a more defensive minded and taller shooting guard on them for defense.  This keeps the point guards out of foul trouble, as well.  As for substitutions, again its going to depend on the situation.